# exim4 sends local mail externaly

Tags: linux, exim

My `exim4` MTA sends local mail externally, that should not be. I have tried to set the variable `dc_other_hostnames` to the local hostname. But that doesn´t work. If I send mail with `mail root -s Test` to root the mail is tried to deliver externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your routers section.  The routers section contain router definitions which are checked in the order they appear in exim.conf. Each router has a condition. If the condition evaluates to true, exim uses that router.

The router you want to use is *probably* near the bottom of the router list and named either "localuser" or "system_aliases".

The problem you might be having is that exim is using one of the earlier routers in your router list. The solution might be to fix that router's condition so that it does *not* match local accounts.  Something like this:

```
domains = ! +local_domains
```

`local_domains` is a variable list defined near the top of your exim.conf file, before the router section. It looks something like this:

```
domainlist local_domains = @ : localhost : localhost.localdomain : mydomain.com : myotherdomain.net
```

The first step in diagnosing the problem is discovering which router is being used for the problem address. Run the following:

```
exim -bt root
```

The output of the command should be something like this:

```
myuseraccount@mydomain
    <-- myuser@mydomain
    <-- root@mydomain
  router = localuser, transport = local_delivery
```

Use the `router = ???` part to figure out which router is misconfigured.

Comment: When i run "exim -bt root" the router section contains: router = hub_user_smarthost.

Comment: I fixed it with adding "! + local_domains" to the domain section of the routers "hub_user" and "hub_user_smarthost"